# Insert Keyframe doesn't put keyframe in animator timeline

Tags: animation

I'm making a simple character in blender. I want to animate it, so in pose mode, I rotated the bones a bit and pressed I to insert keyframe.

[image]

When I click the Location, rotation, and scale button however, no keyframes appear in the animation timeline window. I'm probably forgetting something really dumb. Can anybody tell me what it is?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out why. It's because I wasn't in the *Action Editor*.

Comment: i am sorry, but i have to disappoint you. If you are in pose mode (and the color of your bones gives this impression) and if you keyframe now your selected bones with "I" in the viewport this WILL work. The reason in your case why it might not work is, that you had no keyframes before and you press I while your cursor was on the timeline (or even another reason). So...sorry, your answer is wrong.